# Unable to change layout of checkout_onepage_success?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, layout-update

I have a `checkout_onepage_success.xml` file in the view/frontend/layout directory of my module but changing the layout attribute of the `<page>` tag from `layout="1column"` to `layout="2columns-right"` does not change the layout of the page.

Other updates in the file work fine, I can add, modify and remove blocks as normal but the page layout will not change. If I remove the `layout="1column"` from the core `module-checkout` module, leaving it with no declared layout, my layout update then DOES work and the page is 2cols-right.

Attempted to solve this by `<sequence>`ing my module after the core `module-checkout` but it looks like the core layout is still being processed after mine and taking precedence.

What do?

Comment: Looks like your module isn't taking precedent over the core. Have you tried to simply add checkout_onepage_success.xml to your theme and do the change to make sure it isn't a theme issue? Or switch to luma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved - the `<sequence>` wasn't being applied. Needed to disable and re-enable the module.

Less nice solution is to give your module a namespace that begins with a letter that comes after M alphabetically.

Answer (score -1):

create **checkout_onepage_success.xml** in **view/frontend/layout** folder of your module and paste below code in file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
</page>
```

[image]